# Multiple slider trackbar for windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Does anyone have any idea on how to create a trackbar with multiple sliders in WinForms? I would like to mark a range. Also, is it possible to offset the sliders vertically a little bit? My goal would be to have two sliders above the trackbar, and two below it.

```
     v-----------------v
________________________________________
                                ^------^
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by writing your own `UserControl` where you handle the mouse events and painting yourself. You would need several hit test regions; one for each thumb.

To draw the trackbar, you would need a combination of [`ControlPaint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlpaint.aspx) and the theming APIs provided by the [`System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.aspx) namespace. Most notably, the  [`VisualStyleElement.TrackBar.ThumbTop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstyleelement.trackbar.thumbtop.aspx), [`VisualStyleElement.TrackBar.ThumbBottom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstyleelement.trackbar.thumbbottom.aspx), and [`VisualStyleElement.TrackBar.Track`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstyleelement.trackbar.track.aspx) for drawing the thumbs and track respectively.

You use the `ControlPaint` calls to draw a frame and buttons for the track and thumbs when theming is unavailable (such as on Win2k or when theming is disabled).

Comment: I have not done anything like this before. If I draw everything my self, is there any way to still get the "standard" behaviour for the tumbs and ticks, or would I have to design that as well?

Comment: Unfortunately, you would need to design and code that yourself. There are visual styles for drawing the ticks when theming is available, but you are responsible for determining the layout, handling keyboard and mouse interaction, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw your own using `ControlPaint` to make sure the rendering is consistent with the rest of your UI.

Comment: I have never used ControlPaint before. Could you describe in a little more detail how it would be done?